# What image file formats are commonly imported into Keynote and PowerPoint for Mac?

Tags: ms-office, graphics, keynote

I am a Windows user, but my superior colleague is a Mac user (he has a MacBook).  He has asked me to send him some images that I used in a PDF report.  He would like to include these (original high-resolution) images in a presentation that he will make (almost certainly using either Keynote or PowerPoint for Mac).  Since I'm very unfamiliar with Mac (embarrassingly, I have not owned a Mac computer since 1997!), what file format(s) do you think that I should send these images in?

In Windows, here are some common formats:

- [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) for photographs
- [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif) or [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) for graphics (e.g., graphical schematics, graphs, charts).  Specifically, I actually originally imported PNG images into my PDF report.
- [EPS (Encapsulated PostScript)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) for graphics (e.g., graphical schematics, graphs, charts)

Are these image formats *easily* compatible with Mac and *easily* importable into Keynote/PowerPoint?  Or does Mac have something better that I should convert them to for use in Keynote/PowerPoint?  I'm particularly interested in an image format that will easily and nicely store graphs and charts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these are standard image formats that OS X, Keynote, and PowerPoint for Mac all support.

There are not any special Mac graphics formats that would be better for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is not true since I am trying to add a photo taken in 2011 to either windows power point 2019 or keynote and both report a problem with the format being unsupported.

Comment: What is the format of the photo?  What app do you use to view it on your Mac?